# Will this equation ever have an integer value?

Tags: polynomials, integers

Given two odd numbers a and b, will this equation:

$$\frac{2ab-a^2+b^2}{2a-2b}$$

ever have an integer value?

Comment: No. Subtract and add $b^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Putting $a=2m+1,b=2n+1$ and dividing, we get $-(m-n)+\frac{(2n+1)^2}{2(m-n)}$. This is an integer if and only if $\frac{(2n+1)^2}{2(m-n)}$ is an integer. However, the numerator of this fraction is odd and the denominator is even.

Comment: @BarryCipra $2ab-a^2+b^2 \ne (a-b)^2-2a^2$

Comment: odd squares are $1 \pmod 4$  The numerator is $2 \pmod 4$  while the denominator is $0 \pmod 4.$  That is, the denominator cannot divide the numerator

Comment: @jjagmath, oh sorry, you're quite right. Deleted! I should have said $${2ab-a^2+b^2\over2a-2b}={2b^2-(a-b)^2\over2(a-b)}={b^2\over a-b}-{a-b\over2}$$